# Find the best $X$ to minimize the diagonal entries of $A^TXA - D$, allowing arbitrarily large off-diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

Given an (arbitrary) matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$ and a diagonal matrix $D \in R^{n \times n}$, I want to find a matrix $X \in R^{m \times m}$ such that the diagonal entries of $A^TXA$ "best approximate" $D$. For now I'm saying that means minimizing the sum of squares of the diagonal entries of $A^TXA - D$, but I'm flexible about altering the definition of "best approximates" if it helps find beautiful solutions. I explicitly do not care about the off-diagonals, and want the smallest possible diagonal values of $A^TXA - D$ at the expense of arbitrarily large off-diagonals.

There's no guarantees about the relationship between $m$ and $n$. In some cases $m < n$, so $X$ is in effect part of a low-rank factorization of $D$. The trouble with the obvious $X = A^{\dagger T}DA^{\dagger}$ is that using psuedo-inverses effectively forces $X$ to try to match the off-diagonal 0's of $D$, which I explicitly *do not want*, because it reduces the accuracy of the diagonals, which are the only values I care about.

What's the best way to solve for $X$? There's obviously gradient descent as a last resort, but that's not very beautiful. It feels like there's something elegant hiding in this problem description. Is there anything clever and closed form I could do?

Comment: I think you have a quadratic program here, which can be explicitly solved. It may even be convex and hence $\mathcal{O}(m^6)$ on interior point methods but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: It certainly _is_ convex, because $A^TXA - D$ is linear in $X$, and taking the sum of squares of the diagonal of a matrix is a convex operation in its input, so by composition the whole thing is convex in $X$. So we certainly could solve it with any convex solver. I'd consider interior point methods to be basically just fancy gradient descent though (and in this case not necessary, because we don't have any inequality constraints). This is for a real-time application, so I'm trying to come up with a clean analytical solution if we can think of one.

Comment: Yeah, I had published on a least squares problem on some Frobenius approximation (MDS) and it ended up being a convex QP. Thought it would be similar here.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on this all morning, and found an analytical solution! I gather from my years of lurking that it's bad form to answer your own question, but I figured I'd post it here for posterity. Let me know if I made any mistakes!

Doing this optimization for just the diagonals in closed form requires a bit of gymnastics, but is possible. We'll use the notation that $a_i$ corresponds to the $i$'th column of $A$, $x_i$ to the $i$'th column of $X$, and $a_{ij}$ is the $j$'th entry of the $a_{i}$ vector. Similarly, $D_{ii}$ corresponds to the $i$'th diagonal entry, and $d$ is the vector of just diagonal entries of $D$.

Let's begin by rewriting the optimization objective directly:

$$\min \sum_i \left( (A^T X A)_{ii} - D_{ii} \right)^2$$

Note that:

$$(A^T X A)_{ii} = a_i^T X a_i = \sum_j \underbrace{a_{ij}}_{\text{scalar}}(a_i^Tx_j) = \sum_j {\underbrace{(a_{ij} a_i)}_{\text{vector}}}^Tx_j$$

So it becomes clear that we could construct a long vector $q \in \mathcal{R}^{m^2}$, which will map to every column of $X$ placed end to end. We can also construct a matrix $W \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m^2}$ where every column $w_i$ is the vectors $a_{ij}a_i$ placed end to end for each $a_i$. Then we have:

$$a_i^T X a_i = w_i^T q$$

Now if we take the diagonals of $D_{ii}$ as entries of a vector $d \in \mathcal{R}^n$, we can write our optimization problem as a linear equation:

$$\min \sum_i ((A^T X A)_{ii} - D_{ii})^2 = \text{min} \,\, \| W^Tq - d \|_2^2$$

This is a standard least squares problem, and it solved when:

$$q = W^{\dagger T} h$$

Once we have a value of $q$, we can reconstruct the original matrix $X$ by taking each column of $X$ the appropriate segment of $q$.

Comment: For notation, I recommend writing $\vec{a}$ for vectors to distinguish them from scalars

Comment: And interestingly, even though you've turned it into a standard linear system, you're still ending up with $\mathcal{O}(m^6)$ complexity.

Comment: Good point! That seems like scratching at some important underlying truth. I had a prof in college who had a theory that P and NP were related to whether the underlying problem could be mapped to a convex optimization problem or not. I should probably benchmark both approaches and check if this is actually faster, cause $W$ does end up being quite large for big $m$

Comment: The truth is probably the simple fact that it's possible to rephrase (at least some) quadratic problems as linear problems... with quadratic blowup in size